# Combining an EditText with loadUrl on WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

If I use **WebView** this way it works as expected.

`webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");`

I tried appending a `loadUrl` with an `EditText` this way:

`webView.loadUrl("http://www." + resultText + ".com");`

The result was:

> "Webpage not available"
>
> "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Edittext variable name is resultText
try this

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www." + resultText.getText().toString() + ".com");
```